# How to handle DDL statements (create,alter,drop) with row based replication for MySql?

Tags: mysql, replication, ddl

The for row based replication MySql documentation states that:

"For statements such as CREATE TABLE ... SELECT, a CREATE statement is generated from the table definition and replicated using statement-based format, while the row insertions are replicated using row-based format."

how does the row based replication handle alter and delete statements? Couldn't find any documentation on that, do i need to re-run those commands onto the replicas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log-setting.html:

> *With the binary log format set to ROW, many changes are written to the binary log using the row-based format. Some changes, however,
>   still use the statement-based format. Examples include all DDL (data
>   definition language) statements such as CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, or
>   DROP TABLE.*

DDL statements are handled with statement based replication, and DML, including deletes are handling with row based replication.

Under normal operation, you should not have to re-run any statements.

Comment: Thank you! I guess i was just not looking in the right part of the manual!